# use solr for /search

Tags: 7, search

In my site (camperlife.it) I have installed sorl + search api solr and all works for sections where solr is active (like /aree-di-sosta-italia.html). Now I want to substitute /search (search modules) with search api + solr.

Is there a module/way to do it (simple) or I need to create a view for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just disable the core search module for performance reasons and create a view with [Search API views](https://drupal.org/node/1597930) unless you're already using panels and you can integrate a much richer solution, for example the one described in: http://ygerasimov.com/ajaxified-solr-search-drupal-search-api-views-panels

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [@pcambra's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2322/pcambra) response is to the use the [Search API Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page) module. As the d.o. page describes;

> This module is for creating simple search pages for the Search API project, not using Views or any other modules. They can be used when a view would be unnecessarily slow or complex, or for quickly testing out functionality. They also provide search blocks for starting a search from anywhere on the site.

Like pcambra, I'd disable native search if I have my site SOLR-indexed.